# HTML: how to change color of an image on click

Tags: html, button, colors

I have two html codes: one is a table with grey square buttons and the other one is the same table but the only difference is that the buttons are orange.

When I click on a grey button, I'd like it to be orange and stay orange. Please, how can I do this?

Comment: Please post code showing what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the :visited selector. Basically, you take the button that you want to make orange, and set the a:link to whatever background color (grey) and then for that same button, set a:visited to background-color (orange). Here's some further reading if you need:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_visited.asp

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether you were talking about a link button, try this, it might work.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried with javascript?
jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").click(function(){
        $(this).css("background","#FF6600"); // your color
    });
});
```